# Php how to prevent auto form submit on page load or refresh with F5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the below form and its works fine but when i refresh the page using F5 or however it re submit the form.
How can i prevent the auto submission of the form on pageload or refresh. But im using it submit on `onchange`.

Im using it to update the delivery charge in database only if i will select the different area from dropdown. When i select and different area, it updates the area in Database but when refreshes the page it selects the first row in the list and auto submit the form and update that value in the database.

**cart_update_delivery.php**

```
$uid    =   $_POST['area'];

$total  =   mysql_query("
update orders_temp
set area = '".$uid."'
where user_id = 1
");
```

**.........**

```
<script>
function submitForm(){
    var val = document.myform.area.value;
    if(val!=-1){
        document.myform.submit();
    }
}
</script>
<iframe name="q" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<form action="cart_update_delivery.php" method="post" target="q" name="myform">
<select onchange="submitForm();" name="area" data-placeholder="Select area" class="test">
    <optgroup label="0001">
    <option style="" value="1"> A</option>
    <option style="" value="2"> B</option>
    <optgroup label="0002">
    <option style="" value="3"> C</option>
    <option style="" value="4"> D</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reload the page after submitting

```
<script>
    function submitForm(){
        var val = document.myform.area.value;
        if(val!=-1){
            document.myform.submit();
            location.reload(true);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you should just check whether you have POST data or not. Otherwise you will have your db record rewritten each time your page is loaded.

```
if (isset($_POST['area'])) 
{
    $uid   = $_POST['area'];
    $total = mysql_query("
    update orders_temp
    set area = '" . $uid . "'
    where user_id = 1
    ");
}
```

Comment: This answer has a SQL injection flaw. Please don't use this.

Comment: The answer was not about the SQL request itself but about preventing code execution after simple page refresh.

Comment: I know it is not, but I still felt like mentioning it in case people would copy + paste it to their own code without thinking about the SQL injection possibility.

Answer (score -2):

In php, you can forward the browser to a fresh page by using a http header after your update. The header must be sent before anything else.

```
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

See [PHP: header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)